# Some questions about PDO, safety and correct syntax

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I apologize if this may be a ready-made topic, but I need an answer in detail. I would like to learn to program in PDO, but I have lots of bases being self-taught.

I have a few simple questions:

1) Program in PDO is equally satisfying to create your own scripts or is an old and unsafe method? Schedule in OOP when I get quite complex.

2) programming in PDO, what are the correct Prepared Statement to be written? Pass the data-bind?

3) As an example of security, this script for login and user registration using a library to encrypt your password, so it is quite safe against attacks?

http://thisinterestsme.com/php-user-registration-form/

I repeat, I know that I would find some answers to my questions, but I need answers to my details, thanks.

Comment: This is a better post for a discussion forum, not Stackoverflow.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The manual has a whole section on how to use prepared statements using the PDO, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php. PDO is not out of date, again view manual, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDO and mysqli are both safe methods which you can use.
the link you have attached - http://thisinterestsme.com/php-user-registration-form/

is great! shows you how to make an easy query :

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(username) AS num FROM users WHERE username = :username";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

//Bind the provided username to our prepared statement.
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);

//Execute.
$stmt->execute();

//Fetch the row.
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and the password hash is great if you have PHP version 5.5+.

In addition, you can also review the website http://www.phptherightway.com

You will find there very interesting documentations of how to program a secured code.

Good luck and be awesome! :)